How do I create a multi-indexed DataFrame from a double-nested dictionary?
I am trying to create a pandas multi-indexed DataFrame from a double-nested dictionary but am quite stumped as to how to do this.
As some background I have scraped some data from a website and put it into this nested dictionary form as I thought it would be easiest to work with (but I appear to be wrong :D)...
The nested dictionary currently looks like this and I want to put this into a DataFrame that has the ID of the fighter as the column so that in the case of multiple fighters, each column would represent a new fighter, the fight number (0 or 1 in this example as the first row index) with the inner level being the fight details (e.g., date, fighter weight etc).
{
   'ID':{
      0:{
         'date ↕':'2024-05-23',
         'Fighter Weight':'',
         'Opponent':'fighter_1',
         'Opponent Weight':'',
         'w-l-d':('11', '0', '0'),
         'result':'VS',
         'rounds':'12'
      },
      1:{
         'date ↕':'2022-08-28',
         'Fighter Weight':'227¾',
         'Opponent':'Fighter_2',
         'Opponent Weight':'211',
         'result':'W-SD',
         'rounds':'12/12'
      }
   }
}

On the initial run when I ran DataFrame.from_dict(data) this yields an output where the values of the DataFrame is the inner dictionary.
Here is what I would like the dataframe to look like. Note that I have just shown selected fight details for brevity here
                           ID
0 Date             2024-05-23
  Fighter Weight             
  Opponent          fighter_1
  Opponent Weight            
  w-l-d            (11, 0, 0)
  result                   VS
  rounds                   12
1 Date             2022-08-28
  Fighter Weight         227¾
  Opponent          Fighter_2
  Opponent Weight         211
  w-l-d                      
  result                 W-SD
  rounds                12/12

If you think it would be better to store the data into something other than a nested dictionary then also please let me know as I am open to making changes to the scraper as well.

can you provide desired output as table?

@PandaKim I will upload something in a moment. Thanks!

Why are the Dates floats in the screenshot? Shouldn't they be a datetimes? Hmm, but then you'd have mixed dtypes in the column, so shouldn't Date be a column?

@wjandrea I just generated some random numbers to show how I want this to look like. I cannot actually get my data into the desired format yet. That is a fair point with regard to dates - my plan was to only use the dates to compute time between fights as additional features etc

Have just edited this with the actual values now.

"ID of the fighter as the column" - So why do you have "ID" as a column label? Where are the fighter IDs in this data? Did you just put "ID" as a placeholder for an actual ID? I imagine an actual ID would be something like "george_foreman" for example.

Sorry for the confusion but the solution below from keepAlive works. I want to have each column representing a fighters resume and for me, this ID will be a number in a database.

@InvestingScientist OK, show us that. With Pandas, it's important to be clear what's a label and what's the actual data.

With data consisting of
data = {
   'fighter1':{
      0:{
         'date ↕':'2024-05-23',
         'Fighter Weight':'',
         'Opponent':'fighter_1',
         'Opponent Weight':'',
         'w-l-d':('11', '0', '0'),
         'result':'VS',
         'rounds':'12'
      },
      1:{
         'date ↕':'2022-08-28',
         'Fighter Weight':'227¾',
         'Opponent':'Fighter_2',
         'Opponent Weight':'211',
         'result':'W-SD',
         'rounds':'12/12'
      }
   },
   # Partial copy of fighter 1 (second instance removed)
   'fighter2':{
      0:{
         'date ↕':'2024-05-23',
         'Fighter Weight':'',
         'Opponent':'fighter_1',
         'Opponent Weight':'',
         'w-l-d':('11', '0', '0'),
         'result':'VS',
         'rounds':'12'
      },
   }
}

what about using pandas.concat ? As follows
df = pd.concat(
    axis=1, objs=[
        pd.DataFrame(data=datum).unstack().to_frame(id_)
        for id_, datum in data.items()
    ]
)

>>> df
                     fighter1    fighter2
0 date ↕           2024-05-23  2024-05-23
  Fighter Weight                         
  Opponent          fighter_1   fighter_1
  Opponent Weight                        
  w-l-d            (11, 0, 0)  (11, 0, 0)
  result                   VS          VS
  rounds                   12          12
1 date ↕           2022-08-28         NaN
  Fighter Weight         227¾         NaN
  Opponent          Fighter_2         NaN
  Opponent Weight         211         NaN
  w-l-d                   NaN         NaN
  result                 W-SD         NaN
  rounds                12/12         NaN

An example of use via pandas.IndexSlice
>>> df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'result'], :]
         fighter1 fighter2
0 result       VS       VS
1 result     W-SD      NaN



Thank you! The issue for this becomes when I have more than one ID. What I want to do is train a model to predict the outcome of a given bout and I think I would need to have this within a single dataframe.

Ok @InvestingScientist, first, see how df abvove looks like what you want. Be that as it may, you data sample is misleading. How is it structured exactly ? For example, is it something like {'ID1': {'figher0': {}, 'figher1': {}}, 'ID2': {'figher12': {}, 'figher13': {}}} ?

It is structured as I have shown above: the ID is the fighter ID (the outer key) and the numbers 0 and 1 are two instances of this fighters fights. So where you have fighter0, in my data this is the their nth fight and then the inner dict you have should hold the info about the fight {'date ↕': '2024-05-23',    'Fighter Weight': '',    'Opponent': 'fighter_1',    'Opponent Weight': '',    'w-l-d': ('11', '0', '0'),    'result': 'VS',    'rounds': '12'}

This is great and works perfectly, thank you very much. Will look into exactly what it is doing as well.
